# Network services deleted via terminal reenabled after Restart

Tags: terminal, network, bash, script

I have written a shell script to remove all services excluding ethernet. The aim is to remove these services and PPPoE entries so the end user only sees ethernet under Preferences > Networking.

However, after a restart the services return. This also happens with just running the terminal command  `networksetup deletepppoeservice [servicename]`

I presume there is a plist somewhere that repopulates these entries, however I have deleted networkInterfaces.plist to no effect.

Here is the code snippet in question:

```
SERVICE="Ethernet"
for NETSERV in ${networkService[@]}; do
    if [[ "$NETSERV" != "$SERVICE" ]]; then
        networksetup deletepppoeservice "$NETSERV";
    fi
doneSERVICE="Ethernet"
for NETSERV in ${networkService[@]}; do
    if [[ "$NETSERV" != "$SERVICE" ]]; then
        networksetup deletepppoeservice "$NETSERV";
    fi
done
```

The goal:
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Update. When changing the services through the GUI the plist files changes as expected, however when modifying via terminal a preferences.plist.old file is created in /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/ .However, deleting this file or using it to replace the preferences.plist file still doesn't give the intended result.

Comment: Tried to chown the preferences.plist and added an exit statement to the script to avoid any loose ends and still no change. Maybe I need to lock the plist with a lockfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution that I stumbled on was to lock the file using `chflags uchg /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist` so whatever was modifying it back was denied. Oddly, it was a root owned file so whatever was modding it was root.

I ran `sudo fs_usage | grep /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist` and saw no write or modify commands so it had to happen on boot or login.